# Why bool.try parse not parsing value to TRUE OR FALSE

Tags: c#

Please consider the following code.

```
bool somevariable;
bool.TryParse(Convert.ToString(Dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SomeColumnName"]), out somevariable);
CheckBox.Checked = somevariable;
```

In "SomeColumnName" in dataset, I have value as 1. So I assume that this will parse this 1 as TRUE in "somevariable".

But when I try to parse this value to bool, it always returns as false.

I don't know why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [`Boolean.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.parse.aspx) documentation:

> true if value is equivalent to the value of the Boolean.TrueString field; false if value is equivalent to the value of the Boolean.FalseString field.

`1` and `0` are not equivalent to the strings `"true"` or `"false"`.

Assuming your `SomeColumnName` is indeed a boolean field, you can do:

```
return Convert.ToString(Dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SomeColumnName"]) == "1";
```

Or directly convert to boolean (thanks @Bolu):

```
return Convert.ToBoolean(Dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SomeColumnName"]);
```

Comment: ok, thanks. Could you tell what is the best way to check for TRUE or FALSE in my case?

Comment: @Oded: Can I use: `Convert.ToBoolean(Dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SomeColumnName"])` ?

Comment: Beware of NULL and better use Convert.ToString() function.

Comment: @Deepak - This depends on your data and expectation from it. You have not mentioned _anywhere_ that the value might be `NULL`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my routine that is in a file shared by many projects:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Legal values: Case insensitive strings TRUE/FALSE, T/F, YES/NO, Y/N, numbers (0 => false, non-zero => true)
    /// Similar to "bool.TryParse(string text, out bool)" except that it handles values other than 'true'/'false' and handles numbers like C/C++
    /// </summary>
    public static bool TryParseBool(object inVal, out bool retVal)
    {
        // There are a couple of built-in ways to convert values to boolean, but unfortunately they skip things like YES/NO, 1/0, T/F
        //bool.TryParse(string, out bool retVal) (.NET 4.0 Only); Convert.ToBoolean(object) (requires try/catch)
        inVal = (inVal ?? "").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
        switch ((string)inVal)
        {
            case "TRUE":
            case "T":
            case "YES":
            case "Y":
                retVal = true;
                return true;
            case "FALSE":
            case "F":
            case "NO":
            case "N":
                retVal = false;
                return true;
            default:
                // If value can be parsed as a number, 0==false, non-zero==true (old C/C++ usage)
                double number;
                if (double.TryParse((string)inVal, out number))
                {
                    retVal = (number != 0);
                    return true;
                }
                // If not a valid value for conversion, return false (not parsed)
                retVal = false;
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Taken [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse.aspx)

> When this method returns, if the conversion succeeded, contains true if value is equivalent to Boolean.TrueString or false if value is equivalent to FalseString. If the conversion failed, contains false. The conversion fails if value is null or is not equivalent to the value of either the TrueString or FalseString field.

`1` is not equivalent to `Boolean.TrueString` (`"true"` or any case variant) so the conversion fails (`TryParse` returns `false`) and the out parameter (in this case `somevariable`) is set to `default(bool)` which is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

If "1" is as string it'll not parse it as boolean true. If it is "true" as string then it'll parse it as boolean true.

Answer (score 0):

Created an extension method, based on @Mick Bruno's answer, which may help people?

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool TryParseBoolean(this string value, out bool result)
    {
        value = (value ?? "").ToString().Trim().ToLower();
        switch (value)
        {
            case "true":
            case "t":
            case "yes":
            case "y":
            case "1":
                result = true;
                return true;
            case "false":
            case "f":
            case "no":
            case "n":
            case "0":
                result = false;
                return true;
            default:
                result = false;
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And use like this...

```
bool boolValue;
var stringValue = "true";

if (stringValue.TryParseBoolean(out boolValue))
    // do something here...
```